# Run function after Thread has finished running

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

I'm trying to run a function after a thread has completed running. My thread starts when an UI button is pressed and the thread takes a while to complete.
Once it's done running I want to call a function. Here is the code I tried so far. When I try to run my code the thread never executes and the application freezes. Any suggestion on how to fix this would be helpful.

```
public bool StartProbe()
{
    if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(ObsProbeFolder, "probePJM.exe")))
    {
        ThreadStart ProbeThreadStart = new ThreadStart(() =>
        // right side of lambda    
            {
               // does stuff
            });

            ProbeThread = new Thread(ProbeThreadStart);
            ProbeThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
            ProbeThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            ProbeThread.Start();

    }
    else
    {                      
        return false;
    }

    // waiting for thread to finish 
    ProbeThread.Join();
    // run a function
    loadData();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why did you wrap your `ProbeThread.Join();` in a for loop?

Comment: I initially tired it without a for loop, but it was still giving me the same problem. So I tired it with a for loop to see if it would fix, but it didn't.

Comment: The application freezes when you do a `someThread.Join();` on the UI thread, since the UI thread will block until the other thread has stopped.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a BackgroundWorker?

Comment: To follow up what Maarten said, I recommend you look at async/await methods as they've been designed for this use case.

Comment: @mjhouseman the reason why I can't use a BackgroundWorker is because the Thread modifies some of the data in the UI.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19985988/125740

Comment: @Satish You can use the object's Dispatcher's invoke method to access the UI element you need to change (from within Worker_DoWork)

Comment: What's the `ProbeThreadStart` method looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a BackgroundWorker:

```
Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            Worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;

            Worker.RunWorkerAsync(new BackgroundArguments()
            {
                // arguments
            });
```

Work on alternate thread:

```
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{       
    // do stuff
}
```

Return to UI thread:

```
private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       // load data or whatever on UI thread
    }
```

Comment: Why use such an old structure as BackgroundWorker, if you can use TPL and/or await?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using BackgroundWorker, especially for a single process such as the user described. I agree that TPL is better for running multiple processes, but for a single process they are virtually interchangeable.